# Redis - configure parameters vm-page-size and vm-pages

Tags: redis

Using Redis, I am currently parameterizing the redis.conf for using virtual memory.

Regarding I have 18 millions of keys (max 25 chars) as hashtables with 4 fields (maximum 256 chars)

My server has 16 Go RAM.

I wonder how to optimize the parameters vm-page-size (more than 64 ?) and vm-pages.

Any ideas ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't need to in this case - your usage is pretty close to standard. It's only when your values are large ( > ~4k iirc) that you can run into issues with insufficient contiguous space.

Also, with 16GB available there won't be much swapping happening, which makes the vm config a lot less important.

Comment: Indeed I made a test with VM and there were no efficient result